# Is it good practice to forbid constructor in static-only class?

Tags: php, static-class

In the application I am working on, there are some classes with only static functions.

These classes do not follow the Singleton pattern. Consider them just as "tools".

Not real example:

```
class MathHelper {
    public static function plus($num1, $num2)
    {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}
```

Would it be good practice to forbid the construction with ...

```
    private function __construct()
    {
    }
```

just to prevent such class to be instantiated?

Comment: I consider it a good practice, not sure it's explicitly defined as pattern or similar

Answer (score 0):

You could define the class as abstract to prevent instantiation.

```
abstract class MathHelper {
    public static function plus($num1, $num2)
    {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

echo MathHelper::plus(1,2); // 3
$math = new MathHelper(); // Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class MathHelper
```

Comment: Yea, but you can extend it.

Answer (score 0):

declare the constructor as private, and don't define the function.
Clause 6 of book 《effective C++》 talks about this.

```
class MathHelper {
public:
    static function plus($num1, $num2)
    {
    return $num1 + $num2;
    }
private:
    MathHelper ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @ian-brindley answered, you could prevent instantiation by declaring your class `abstract` but if you also want to declare that class also as `final` you can omit the `abstract` and throw an excption in the constructor:

```
<?php
final class MyClass
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    throw new \Exception();
  }
}
```